# Mailchimp cURL "Add Member" Error

Tags: php, curl, mailchimp

I tried referring to one of the answers on StackOverflow to create a new member in a list that I currently own. I am trying to use API v3.0. Below is the code excerpt.

```
        $apikey = 'api_key_here';
        $auth = base64_encode( 'user:'.$apikey );

        $data = array(
            'apikey'        => $apikey,
            'email_address' => '1111111@gmail.com',
            'status'        => 'subscribed',
            'merge_fields'  => array(
                'FNAME' => 'Mihir'
            )
        );
        $json_data = json_encode($data);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/my_list_id_here/members/');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
                                                    'Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);                                                                                                                  

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        var_dump($result);
        die('Mailchimp executed');
```

Here is the error reply I am receiving:

```
        string(218) "{"type":"http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/error-docs/404-resource-not-found","title":"Resource Not Found","status":404,"detail":"The requested resource could not be found.","instance":"f03f3b5d-ef59-4452-b502-8a96449025df"}"
```

Help is much appreciated :)

Thanks,
Mihir.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

What I'm assuming you did: Navigated to Lists, found the list you were trying to add a member to, and took the ID get parameter out of the URL.

If that is the case, what you need to do is: Go to the admin page for the list you are trying to add a member to. Click on the Settings dropdown menu. Go to "List name and defaults". Then use the ID located in the "List ID" section of that page.

Comment: Nearly two years later and this helped me. Thanks

Comment: Same thing as the OP happening to me, but this answer did not work for me, even though I use the correct list id.

Comment: In addition to List ID, verify your URL. It should have .api. NOT .admin. in the address. https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/...

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I'm really surprised that Mailchimp docs and other SDK docs didn't make this clearer.

Answer (score 6):

Navigate to Lists > Settings > There you will see a List ID:

[image]

Comment: Same thing as the OP happening to me, but this answer did not work for me, even though I use the correct list id.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because it can't find the list. To check, try issuing a `GET` to `/3.0/lists/your_list_id_here`. If that returns a 200, you'll want to talk to support because everything else above looks fine. If you get a 404, then you'll need to get the correct list ID (which you can find from doing a `GET` on `/lists/`).

Also: your life will be made immeasurably easier by not using cURL directly. I recommend either [Guzzle](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fguzzle.readthedocs.org%2F&ei=zg-UVam3DpDVoAT77oTwBw&usg=AFQjCNG-ZH8xOPuT5-uz9IVLuFzU3Ta2yQ&sig2=9NClnWJ-0OXEoP_Lv29D2w&bvm=bv.96952980,d.cGU) or [PHP Requests](https://github.com/rmccue/Requests)